# How to repeat an action against all clips in a sequence in Premiere Pro CC

Tags: premiere

I have a large number of individual clips in one sequence of varying lengths. I want to shorten them all, regardless of where in the footage to a certain length (lets say 0 to 10 seconds. If it less than 10 seconds, lets leave it or cut). Going through all of these clips and shortening them manually would take a lot of time.

What I'm looking for is a way to apply the an action (in this case shortening the video, but the action could be arbitrary) to all of the clips, either by selecting all of the clips at once, or by running each clip through a macro where it applies the action with one click (or shortcut).

Is there a way to do this in Adobe Premiere or should I look for a different tool and perform this batch action outside of Adobe Premiere?

Here is a screenshot example of the series of clips.
[image: screenshot]

Edit:

I was able to do what I wanted using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and a [Ruby script that I created](https://gist.github.com/cdesch/c2bef6becc696034c290). Here is a video showing the script in action:

**Although I was able to solve the problem at hand, I think the original question still stands:  Can you repeat and action (somewhat complex action) against multiple clips in Adobe Premiere in batch or select multiple fashion?**

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has included a scripting framework in most of its apps, (you may have noticed a tool called extendscript toolbox, that's the IDE for it). Unfortunately they neglected to document Premiere's scripting API, so you have to work it out yourself / using [the internet](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1558936).

So yes, you could indeed develop a script to do this within Premiere. After all, why spend hours doing something by hand when in only a few weeks you can develop a script to do it automatically?